# not able to get API response by passing email as parameter in angular

Tags: angular, api, http, post, service

I am not able to get response by calling Rest API post method also i tried on postman got it the response.

I have tried the following code:
data.service.ts

getcategories(){

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
let params1 = new HttpParams().set('email',"info@evidyahub.com");
let options = {
     headers: headers
 }
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'/courses/get_all_courses/', {params:params1},options);


 }

home.componenet.ts;

categories:any;

  ngOnInit() {

console.log(this.data.getcategories());
this.data.getcategories().subscribe(
 (data)=>{
  this.categories=data;
  console.log(data);
},
(err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{    
  console.log("Error in API");
}


);}
```

by calling the api got it null

Comment: Use an proxy config file

Comment: I have already used proxy config but same issue?

Comment: can you show the error in the question? network tab response

Comment: I have got it following: {"params":{"updates":[{"param":"email","value":"info@evidyahub.com","op":"s"}],"cloneFrom":{"updates":null,"cloneFrom":null,"encoder":{},"map":null},"encoder":{},"map":null}}

Comment: Use `home.componenet.ts;` not as codes and use `getcategories(){` as codes. Sorry for the edit. It should be also edited

Comment: if your html body empty please pass empty body in `http.post` . This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have got it solution :service file:

getCourse(data:any){

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'/courses/get_all_courses/',data,{headers,responseType: 'json', observe: 'response'});
```

}

.ts file:

```
    const params = {
      email: "info@evidyahub.com"
    }

    this.data.getCourse(params).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        if (!res) return;
        let aa = JSON.stringify(res.body.data);//console.log(aa);
        let getCourses = JSON.parse(aa);
        //console.log(getCourses);
        this.courses = getCourses
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error in API", error)
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'/courses/get_all_courses/',{} ,{params:params1},options);
```

If you are sending http post with empty body send `http.post(url: string, body: any, options:{// options here})`